# How to run multiple Apache Ignite nodes in the same machine?

Tags: caching, ignite

I want to run multiple Ignite nodes on the same VM. Suppose, their address will be localhost:port (a set of ports, as a series). And, I want my Java client application to connect to the nodes.

Can you provide a simple and beginner-level guide to achieve this? The ones I tried are overwhelming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MultipleIgnites {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Ignition.start(new IgniteConfiguration().setIgniteInstanceName("s1")
            .setDataStorageConfiguration(new DataStorageConfiguration()
                .setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(new DataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true))));
        Ignition.start(new IgniteConfiguration().setIgniteInstanceName("s2")
            .setDataStorageConfiguration(new DataStorageConfiguration()
                .setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(new DataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true))));
        Ignition.start(new IgniteConfiguration().setIgniteInstanceName("s3")
            .setDataStorageConfiguration(new DataStorageConfiguration()
                .setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(new DataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true))));
}
```

This will start three of them, connected in one cluster.

Answer (score 1):

See [this documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-isolated-ignite-clusters-on-same-set-of-machines) section that shows how to start isolated clusters in the same environment.